# PushAsync in constructor gives the second page the ToolbarItemes of the first page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

if I do a PushAsync in the constructor on my MainPage, the ToolbarItems from the MainPage are also displayed on the second page. I already tried to switch the toolbar items in the OnAppearing and OnDisappearing triggers on and off. Unfortunately, this is useless. I test on android and I use Visual Studio.

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        this.ToolbarItems.Clear();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {

        var edit = new ToolbarItem
        {
            Icon = "edit.png",
            Command = new Command(this.startEditMode),
        };
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(edit);
        var addpage = new ToolbarItem
        {
            Icon = "connect.png",
            Command = new Command(this.startWebsiteConnector),
        };
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(addpage);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think so. I think this in the Resource.Designer.cs file creates the two ToolbarItems : public static void UpdateIdValues()
  {
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Resource.Attribute.actionBarSize = global::dpsApp.Droid.Resource.Attribute.actionBarSize;
  }

Comment: If you put breakpoints on them, and run the code, is `OnDisappearing` firing before `OnAppearing`?

Comment: Nope OnAppearing is firing first

Comment: Then do the clear first while invoking the appearing function.

Comment: This doesn't work